# Recursively find a word in a grid

Tags: java, recursion, grid, cpu-word

I am working on an algorithm question in order to find a word on the grid.

My solution consists of first finding the first letter of the word in the grid, then if found, recursively go through the 8 directions until every index of the word is matched with the grid indices, and return the string. Attached is my code:

I keep track of my current x and y positions, and then increment the position of the string if and only if there is a match in the index of the word with the index within the grid. However, with this snippet of code, there is something wrong with my recursion causing a stack overflow:

```
public static void findWord(int row, int col, char[][] grid, String w) {
    int rowLength = row;
    int colLength = col;

    char[] word = w.toCharArray();

    for(int j = 0; j < colLength; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
            // Check if first index of word is in this location
            if(word[0] == grid[j][i]) {
                // Iterate through each 8 directions to find the next word
                for(int dir = 0; dir < 8; dir++) {
                    recursiveFind(i, j, i, j, dir, 0, word, grid, rowLength, colLength);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean recursiveFind(
        int initialX, 
        int initialY, 
        int currentX, 
        int currentY, 
        int dir, 
        int currentPos, 
        char[] word, 
        char[][] grid, 
        int rowLength, 
        int colLength) 
{
    // base case is if currentPos == length of word
    if(word.length == currentPos) {
        System.out.println("Initial: " + initialX + " " + initialY);
        System.out.println("Final: " + currentX + " " + currentY);
    }

    if(dir == 0) { // 1
        currentX = currentX; // 0
        currentY -= 1; // -1
    } else if(dir == 1) {
        currentX += 1; // 1
        currentY -= 1; // -1
    } else if(dir == 2) {
        currentX += 1; // 1
        currentY = 0; // 0
    } else if(dir == 3) {
        currentX += 1; // 1
        currentY += 1; // 1
    } else if(dir == 4) {
        currentX = currentX; // 0
        currentY += 1;  // 1
    } else if(dir == 5) {
        currentX -= 1; // -1
        currentY += 1; // 1
    } else if(dir == 6) {
        currentX -= 1; // -1
        currentY = currentY; // 0
    } else {
        currentX -= 1; // -1
        currentY -= 1; // -1
    }

    if(currentX < 0 || 
            currentX == rowLength || 
            currentY < 0 || 
            currentY == colLength || 
            grid[currentY][currentX] != word[currentPos]){
        return false;
    }
    return recursiveFind(initialX, initialY, currentX, currentY, dir, currentPos + 1, word, grid, rowLength, colLength);
}
```

Main.java

```
    char[][] myGrid = new char[][]{
            {'H', 'Q', 'W', 'C', 'S'}, 
            {'E', 'S', 'P', 'K', 'D'}, 
            {'D', 'X', 'A', 'F', 'L'}, 
            {'O', 'C', 'H', 'K', 'H'}, 
            {'C', 'T', 'Y', 'C', 'A'}, 
    };

    String myWord = "CODE";

    findWord(5, 5, myGrid, myWord);
```

I am currently trying to put some debug statements to see what the issue is, however, if someone is willing to give me some assistance on this, it will be highly appreciated!

EDIT:

I fixed the Stack Overflow issue by `return true` in the base case. However, my results are the following, which do not return the expected values I wanted.

```
Initial X: 3, Initial Y: 0, Dir: 0, Current X: 3, Current Y: 0
Initial X: 3, Initial Y: 0, Dir: 1, Current X: 3, Current Y: 0
Initial X: 3, Initial Y: 0, Dir: 2, Current X: 3, Current Y: 0
Initial X: 3, Initial Y: 0, Dir: 3, Current X: 3, Current Y: 0
Initial X: 3, Initial Y: 0, Dir: 4, Current X: 3, Current Y: 0
Initial X: 3, Initial Y: 0, Dir: 5, Current X: 3, Current Y: 0
Initial X: 3, Initial Y: 0, Dir: 6, Current X: 3, Current Y: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it to check that current position is correct and then continue search.
Otherwise, return false.

```
public static boolean recursiveFind(
        int initialX,
        int initialY,
        int currentX,
        int currentY,
        int dir,
        int currentPos,
        char[] word,
        char[][] grid,
        int rowLength,
        int colLength) {
    // base case is if currentPos == length of word
    if (word.length == currentPos) {
        System.out.println("Initial: " + initialX + " " + initialY);
        System.out.println("Final: " + currentX + " " + currentY);
        return true;
    }

    if (currentX >= 0 && currentX < rowLength && currentY >= 0 && currentY < colLength && grid[currentY][currentX] == word[currentPos]) {
        if (dir == 0) { // 1
            currentX = currentX; // 0
            currentY -= 1; // -1
        } else if (dir == 1) {
            currentX += 1; // 1
            currentY -= 1; // -1
        } else if (dir == 2) {
            currentX += 1; // 1
            currentY = 0; // 0
        } else if (dir == 3) {
            currentX += 1; // 1
            currentY += 1; // 1
        } else if (dir == 4) {
            currentX = currentX; // 0
            currentY += 1; // 1
        } else if (dir == 5) {
            currentX -= 1; // -1
            currentY += 1; // 1
        } else if (dir == 6) {
            currentX -= 1; // -1
            currentY = currentY; // 0
        } else {
            currentX -= 1; // -1
            currentY -= 1; // -1
        }

        return recursiveFind(initialX, initialY, currentX, currentY, dir, currentPos + 1, word, grid, rowLength, colLength);
    }

    return false;

}
```

EDIT: With your latest edit, the problem is that you're changing currentX/currentY before checking the current position.

This piece of code:

```
if(currentX < 0 || 
        currentX == rowLength || 
        currentY < 0 || 
        currentY == colLength || 
        grid[currentY][currentX] != word[currentPos]){
    return false;
}
```

must occur before you do:

```
if(dir == 0) { // 1
    currentX = currentX; // 0
    currentY -= 1; // -1
} else if(dir == 1) {
    currentX += 1; // 1
    currentY -= 1; // -1
} else if(dir == 2) {
    currentX += 1; // 1
    currentY = 0; // 0
} else if(dir == 3) {
    currentX += 1; // 1
    currentY += 1; // 1
} else if(dir == 4) {
    currentX = currentX; // 0
    currentY += 1;  // 1
} else if(dir == 5) {
    currentX -= 1; // -1
    currentY += 1; // 1
} else if(dir == 6) {
    currentX -= 1; // -1
    currentY = currentY; // 0
} else {
    currentX -= 1; // -1
    currentY -= 1; // -1
}
```

Or else you're not really checking the current position :P

Comment: Wow Brendan - thank you! Happy to see that I was on the right track, but got some of my order of operations mixed up..

Comment: To reiterate, we have check the position and validity of x and y before we increment/decrement the current positions of x and y, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct. Although I'm not sure if this way is much (if at all) better than just taking whole rows and columns and diagonal strips and searching for the word using substring : )

Comment: The time complexity of this seems quite high, actually. The first two for-loops account for O(row * length) right off the bat. Now sure what the complexity of the recursion and direction for-loops are.

Answer (score 0):

From a first look, I think the problem might be that you do not terminate the recursion when currentpos reaches the wordlength, so it will keep going until it overflows. The base case should end the recursion, but yours keeps going if the condition for the return false is not met.

Edit:
Im pretty sure the condition for dir 2 should be:

```
else if(dir == 2) {
        currentX += 1; // 1
        currentY = currentY; // 0
    }
```

Otherwise you are restarting your current Y, as you have it now

EDIT:
Also, you should not send currentpos as 0 for the start of the recursion, because it will compare again with the first letter of the word. The recursion should start comparing with the second char, as you already compared the first one. Don't forget to add the return true, and your program should run. I just tried it in my computer.

Comment: Oh - looks like I was missing a "return true!"

Comment: I guessed something like that could be the problem. Did it work?

Comment: Nope. It wouldn't give me the stack overflow error, but it did not correctly return the expected values.

Comment: Your recursion should stop if either x or y go out of bounds, but I don't see you taking that into account anywhere. If the end goal is to find the word you have, why aren't you comparing the current position in the grid to the char you are looking for?

Comment: I may be wrong, but am I not doing that using `grid[currentY][currentX] != word[currentPos]`? What I'm doing is, it only increments the `pos` variable if there's a match in the grid char and word char.

Comment: Sorry, I said that before you changed the condition in that if. Check the edit, do you think that could be causing trouble?

Comment: Oh thanks for that catch. Nope, that did not fix the issue unfortunately.